# SCOM doesn't recognize Regex pattern

Tags: regex, http, nginx, scom

The following Regexp works to match Error 403 with the numbers in range 40-49:

```
HTTP\/[\d.]+.\s+(?:403)\s+(4[0-9])\s+

sometext HTTP/1.1" 403 46 "-" "sometext" ->match
sometext HTTP/1.1" 403 56 "-" "sometext" -> no match
sometext HTTP/1.1" 403 460 "-" "sometext" -> no match
```

Now I set this expression in SCOM to monitor a nginx logfile but

```
/var/opt/microsoft/scx/log/scx.log
```

complains about

```
SCXLogFileProvider DoInvokeMethod - invalid regexp : HTTP\/[\d.]+.\s+(?:403)\s+(4[0-9])\s+
```

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Could be different regex flavors. Study the documetnation to find out what regex features are supported. Try replacing `\s` with `[[:blank:]]`, `\d` with `[[:digit:]]` and/or `+` with `{1,}`. Things like that. Lookaheads like `(?:...)` are hard to replace....

Comment: @Yunnosch `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, not a lookahead.

Comment: @Nick You are right (`(?=)` != `(?:)`). Could you explain the difference? (This is meant as "please enlighten me", not as "I think you are wrong".) It currently seems useable similarily to me. Can one be used to replace the other? When? When not?

Comment: @Yunnosch a lookahead doesn't absorb any characters from the input string, it is merely an assertion that what is inside the group matches what is next in the string. A non-capturing group also matches those characters but does absorb them. Try matching [`(?=a)a`](https://regex101.com/r/zhcutx/1) or [`(?:a)a`](https://regex101.com/r/zhcutx/1) against `a` and you will see the difference.

Comment: @Nick Thanks. I also found out by experimenting. Matches `(?:)` for example end up as part of "total match".

Comment: So the OP-helpful result is: `(?:403)` can be replaced by `(403)`, if you then can ignore that first capture group by other means (e.g. use instead the second).

Comment: Try a more generic regex syntax: `HTTP/[0-9.]+.[ \t]+403[ \t]+(4[0-9])[ \t]` or `HTTP/[0-9.]+. +403 +(4[0-9])[ ]`

Comment: OK, so I have found out that SCOM uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions in order to monitor Linux log files. So how would I write such an RegEx to match Error 403 with the numbers in range 40-49?